# Ajuda .htaccess URL's Amigaveis

Tags: htaccess, url-amigável, mod-rewrite, url-rewrite

Olá,

Eu estou desenvolvendo um compilador online, semelhante ao [IdeOne](http://ideone.com/), e gostaria que os usuários pudessem acessar alguns de seus códigos já feitos no site de forma mais simples.
Atualmente eu utilizo uma pagina `codAnterior.php` para isto, eu passo por GET para ela o ID do código, assim a url fica, `www.site.com/Compilador/codAnterior.php?id=1`, eu gostaria que ficasse `www.site.com/Compilador/1`.

Para isto eu vi que possa utilizar o .htaccess, pensei em utilizar o codigo a seguir, mas não sei se está certo.

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^Compilador\/([a-z,0-9,A-Z,_-]+)\/?$ codAnterior.php?id=$1
```